# Create an simple module to update a log while update or adding the product.Its not working

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

Create a simple module to update a log while update or adding the product.
It is not working.

Below is my coding structure.

config.xml( app\code\local\ORD\UpdatePro\etc\config.xml)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><config>
<modules>
    <ORD_UpdatePro>
         <version>0.0.1</version>
    </ORD_UpdatePro>
</modules>

<global>

     <models>
        <ord_updatepro>
            <class>ORD_UpdatePro_Model</class>
        </ord_updatepro>
     </models>

    <events>
        <catalog_product_save_after>
            <observers>
                    <ord_updatepro>
                        <class>ord_orderreports/observer</class>
                        <method>logUpdate</method>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                    </ord_updatepro>
            </observers>
        </catalog_product_save_after>
    </events>
</global></config>
```

ORD_UpdatePro.xml( app\etc\modules\ORD_UpdatePro.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<modules>
<ORD_UpdatePro>
  <active>true</active>
  <codePool>local</codePool>
  <version>0.1.0</version>
</ORD_UpdatePro>
</modules>
</config>
```

Observer.php (app\code\local\ORD\UpdatePro\Model\Observer.php)

```
<?php class ORD_UpdatePro_Model_Observer{
 public function logUpdate(Varien_Event_Observer $observer){
    $product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
    $name = $product->getName();
    $sku = $product->getSku();       
    Mage::log("{$name} ({$sku}) updated", null, 'product-hansa.log');
}   
}?>
```

I am unable to figure out the issue, whether it's a naming issue or configure issue or what ever.
Can Any one help me to find out my error.it will be great pleasure and thank full.

Answer (score 0):

Try to hook into

```
catalog_product_save_commit_after
```

Comment: Thank you,
What is the different between 
<catalog_product_save_after> and <catalog_product_save_commit_after>